# Find word after regex pattern match

Tags: regex, coldfusion

I am using coldfusion's ReMatch() trying to find all filenames in a string that have a \ at the beginning.  Not having much success.. here is my code so far.

```
<cfset fname='this is a \\green.png folder.  But this one is \\blue.jpg.'>
<cfset matchval=#ReMatch("\\\\\w+",fname)#>
<cfdump var="#matchval#">
```

Outputs \\green and \\blue.
I need green.png blue.jpg

Thanks in advance for the help... I'm sure a regex guru will know this right off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put `\w`, dot inside a character class and make it to repeat one or more times by adding `+` next to that  character class.

```
<cfset matchval=#ReMatch("\\\\(\\w+\\.\\w+)",fname)#>
```

Finally print the index 1 value to get your desired string.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response... They are getting me closer.  They both result in the following:   
\\green.png
\\blue.jpg.

need to not grab the \\ and the period at the end of blue.jpg

Comment: try `<cfset matchval=#ReMatch("(?<=\\\\)\\w+\\.\\w+",fname)#>`

Comment: That generates the following error:
Sequence (?<...) not recognized

Comment: ok, then use the above regex and print the **group index 1** to get your desired output.

Comment: Avinash... one last twist I have noticed... some of the file names I am gathering have a - in them.. like 77-green.png   The regex pattern ignores that... how would I get it to include the -?

Comment: try this `"\\\\([\\w-]+\\.\\w+)"`

Comment: @AvinashRaj, ColdFusion's native regular expressions are based on the Jakarta ORO implementation, so no lookbehind. Just FYI